# In Swift AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) not working in background thread when a UI thread is working along?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multithreading

I am new to swift and started working on Visualizing Audio in shape of form
I am using EZAudio pod. theres a function *microphone()* that is called to get input and an UI thread is used to call another function that update UI by using the data provided through microphone!
what i am trying to do is when UI is updated,on a particular condition based on UI update i have to invoke a vibration along the first thread.
So i made a new thread that invoke the viberation but AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) is not working in the background thread!
i know the code is stupid but please have a look!

```
    func microphone(microphone: EZMicrophone!, hasAudioReceived buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>>, withBufferSize bufferSize: UInt32, withNumberOfChannels numberOfChannels: UInt32) {
//thread to update UI       
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
         self.plot?.updateBuffer(buffer[0], withBufferSize: bufferSize)
                    }

    let maxValue = self.myMax(buffer[0], count: bufferSize)
    if(maxValue>0.2){
            // do something in the background
        let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
       //thread to invoke Viberation
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)    
        }

}
```

please helpp and thanks in advance :)